# React material UI WARNING Tabs only accepts Tab Components as children

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am using material UI tabs .
but for some reason i am getting

**warning** :Tabs only accepts Tab Components as children.

```
Found function (props, context, updater) {
  // This constructor gets overridden by mocks. The argument is used
  // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(this instanceof Constructor, 'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' + 'JSX instead. See: fb.me/react-legacyfactory') : void 0;


// Wire up auto-binding
  if (this.__reactAutoBindPairs.length) {
    bindAutoBindMethods(this);
  }

  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;

  this.state = null;
```

This warning I am facing

My code looks like this

```
return (
     <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="background">
            <Header/>
                    <div className="container">
                        <Tabs>
                            <Tab label="Profile" onActive={this.Profile.bind(this)}>
                                <div>
                                    <Profile/>
                             //this is children class
                                </div>
                            </Tab>

                            <Tab label="Downloads" >
                                <div>
                                    {
                                        data.map((detail)=> {
                                            return <DataContainer item={detail}
                                                              ViewItem = {this.productData.bind(this)}
                                            />
                                        })
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </Tab>
                            <Link to="ItemPreview"> <Tab label="Content">
                            </Tab></Link>
                        </Tabs>
                    </div>
            <Sidebar productname={productspecificdata}/>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the Link tag from this Tab

```
<Link to="ItemPreview"> <Tab label="Content"></Tab></Link>
```

As the warning says, you cannot have a Link tag directly under Tabs. Try adding the link inside the Tab if you want.

Many Material-Ui components have this behaviour/constraint, I remember Table has that as well.

Comment: Do you why it is coming because of that

Comment: I edited the answer to explain why you get the warning.